# Multiple if conditions comparing to one

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

searched around a bit and can't find my exact problem the way I want to fix it.

What is the best way to shorten an if statement when having many conditions vs one check in python 3?

Example:

```
if "a" in word or "b" in word or "c" in word etc...:
    *do this*
```

What is the more correct/shorter way to do this?
I do not want to loop through. (i.e. for i in whatever check if i is in whatever)

I've seen other examples like:

```
if {"a", "b", "c", etc...} in {word}:
    *do this*
```

or

```
if ("a" or "b" or "c" etc....) in word:
    *do this*
```

None of these work.  Please help!

Comment: "I do not want to loop through" - > *accepts an answer which loops through*. If you didn't want to loop through, you could do a regex match against "a|b|c|d", for one option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) built-in function.

> `any(iterable)`
>
> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If
>   the iterable is empty, return `False`.

```
any(s in word for s in {'a', 'b', 'c'})
```

Comment: Although I wouldn't necessarily use a `set` for this.

Comment: Awesome, so fast, thanks!  I had also tried to use "all".  But that wasn't working either.  Appreciate it!